# Using html5 audio from Ember

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ember.js

Im trying to set the html5 audio control with the url of an audio resource. 
In order to check if player can play mp3 or ogg files, I'm using this:

```
var audio = this.$('audio')[0],
    type  = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'mp3' : 'ogg';
```

My first attempt was to append the proper url extension inside the `src` property,

```
App.AudioPlayerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  src: function() {
    var audio = this.$('audio')[0],
        type  = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'mp3' : 'ogg';
    return this.get('url') + '.' + this.get('_type');
  }.property('url')
});
```

But it doesnt work because before template has been rendered, src attribute is evaluated and we cannot access to `this.$('audio')[0]`, also, the property is not reevaluated because `url` has not changed.
so finally I added a `_type` property that is set in `didInsertElement` callback and the `src` checks for its existence. With this, `src` is reevaluated when we set `_type` and when `url` changes.

```
App.AudioPlayerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  src: function() {
    if(Ember.isEmpty(this.get('_type'))) return '';

    return this.get('url') + '.' + this.get('_type');
  }.property('url', '_type'),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var audio = this.$('audio')[0],
        type  = audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg') ? 'mp3' : 'ogg';
    this.set('_type', type);
  }
});
```

I'd like to avoid this check `if(Ember.isEmpty(this.get('_type'))) return '';`, I think is kinda ugly and maybe Ember has a proper solution for this.

These are the templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{audio-player url=url}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/audio-player">
  {{input value=url placeholder='Audio url'}}
  <audio controls {{bind-attr src='src'}} preload="auto">
  </audio>
</script>
```

Working demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cufaho/1/edit?html,js,output